# Unable to run Android application on Motorola XT907

Tags: android, eclipse, driver

I'm having issues running my Android application on a Motorola XT907 phone. I'm using Eclipse. USB debugging is enabled on the device, and I was able to get my application on two other phones, yet I'm having trouble with this one.

Eclipse is set up so that I have to select the device when I run the application.

In my manifest, minSdkVersion is 14, and targetSdkVersion is 19. The phone I'm using is running 4.4.2.

In the project properties, the Project Build Target is set to Android 4.4.2.

I'm running Windows 8.

Here is what I tried so far:

- Rebooted the device.
- Ran commands to restart adb. (adb kill-server, adb start-server)
- Restarted Eclipse
- Restarted my computer

Lastly, I have tried manually installing driver software, but I am unable to do this properly. This was my procedure:

- Open Device Manager
- Right click on XT907 under Portable Devices and select Update Driver Software...
- Select Browse my computer for driver software
- Select Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer
- Select Have Disk...
- Browse to adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321/sdk/extras/google/usb_driver/android_winusb.inf and click Open, then OK

This is where I run into an issue. I get a dialog with the title "Select Device" that says "The folder you specified doesn't contain a compatible software driver for your device. If the folder contains a driver, make sure it is designed to work with Windows for x64-based systems."

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the driver from the motorola site of this phone :

https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/89608/p/30,6720,8577

?

Comment: This did the trick, however, I may be installing this application on several other phones. It would be nice if I had some sort of universal driver so that I don't have to find specific drivers for every device I install this on.

Comment: Google/Android drivers works in several devices (Nexus, &c.), but each manufacturers (Moto, Sony, Htc, &c.) has own drivers per models unfortunately..

Comment: Of course, if you only need to install the application (apk), you can put it visible in some place and install by downloading/install in each device. No drivers needed.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

- on your phone, activate **usb debugging** (and enable ADB);
- connect the phone to the same network of your pc. connect USB too.
- in your command prompt go to your **adb.exe** folder **(.../sdk/platform-tools/)** and execute **adb connect (your mobile IP)**

I use this on my Samsung nexus without drivers installed.

Comment: execute this command on adb folder: **adb shell ip -f inet addr show wlan0** to find your mobile ip address. If dont exist try reboot.